# Why does actioncable allow me to broadcast from my chat_channel.rb but not from my model file (chat.rb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

Basically, I am trying to get saves to the database to be broadcasted to all streamers.

I know that the websocket stream is working because when I call App.call.speak() from the client, the received() function is triggered and I see an alert.

I know that the after_create() method on the model is working because the second function prints to the console.

The broadcast function (ActionCable.server.broadcast()) is being called from the model but simply is not working as it does from the chat_channel.rb

I want to call it from the model.

chat.coffee

```
App.chat = App.cable.subscriptions.create "ChatChannel",
  connected: ->
    # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
    alert("hi")

  speak: (message) ->
    @perform 'speak', message: message
```

chat_channel.rb

```
class ChatChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "chat"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end

  def speak(message)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'chat', message: "hello"
  end
end
```

models/message.rb

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user

  after_create :broadcast, :print_out

  def print_out
    puts "print after create"
  end

  def broadcast
    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'chat', message: "hello"  
  end
end
```

update: I figured it out. See answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to broadcast by creating records in rails console. Thats what didnt work. When I used an ajax request, everything worked as expected.